# How to erase only certain contents from a file in python

Tags: python, erase

I am trying to erase all question marks('?') from a .txt file.
I tried tokenizing all content and printing it back like this:

```
with open('my.txt', 'r') as f:
  tokenized = f.split()
for i in len(tokenized):
  if tokenized[i] == '?':
    tokenized.remove('?')
with open('my.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join(tokenized))
```

but it doesn't remove all question marks and if there are any line breaks or whitespace longer than 1 it removes them.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("my.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read().split("?")
with open("my.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("".join(content))
```

You can also use [replace](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/replace.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string.replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) for that:

```py
with open('my.txt', 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()

with open('my.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content.replace('?', ''))
```

---

The issue with your solution is that you use [string.split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) without any argument for `separator`. By default, it will target any whitespace (including newlines or multiple whitespaces). But you join only by one whitespace, so the end result can be different.